# Resonance Frequencies of Oscillator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I understand that resonance is when the force term increases the natural oscillation of the system.
In the next equation the oscillator has a natural frequency $\omega_0=\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$. But I don't know how to find which frequencies $\omega$ create resonance.

$$y''\left(t\right)+2\zeta y'\left(t\right)+y\left(t\right)=\sin{(\omega t+\phi)}$$

where $\zeta=\frac{c}{2\sqrt{km}}$, $c$ is the friction coefficient, $k$ the elasticity constant and $m$ the mass.
this equation has been rescaled using $y(x)=x(\omega_0t)$.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match MSE quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. Making these improvements will attract more appropriate answers and make the question more valuable for future MSE visitors.

Comment: $\omega_0$ is not in the equation. It is the frequency of the solution without damping term. That's why it is called natural frequency.

Comment: @MykeArya Asking it as a Math question , Just represent it as a order two differential equation. Rest concepts can be discussed in physics.

Comment: You lost $k$ (which should multiply $y$) and $m$ (which should multiply $y''$) from the equation.

Comment: http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~ngray/MATH19662/Section%201%20-%20Second%20Order%20Ordinary%20Differential%20Equations.pdf  This is an overview of the topic;  you want section 1.7.  This is a useful practical application of second order differential equations that is worth understanding.

Comment: @RossMillikan I didn't loose it. The problem has been rescaled by $y(x)=x(\omega_0t)$. I think I will put this in the queation.

Comment: @MykeArya:  OK, that just makes $\omega_0=1$

Comment: @exploringnet You are right. I just wrote what the constants are because I don't know if the person that answers need that information. I'm not interested in any physics, just how to deduce the resonance form a differential equation perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the question is not well-formulated and there are notation ambiguities, I will try to answer. The solution of the differential equation you have written consists of two parts: 1) the general solution of the homogeneous equation $y''+2\zeta y'+y=0$ and 2) a particular solution of the non-homogeneous equation. To find the first part, one should solve the characteristic equation
$$\lambda^2+2\zeta\lambda+1=0\Rightarrow \lambda_{\pm}=-\zeta\pm\sqrt{\zeta^2-1}$$
and then write $y_h(t)=A \cdot e^{\lambda_+ t}+B \cdot e^{\lambda_- t}$ where  $A$ and $B$ are two arbitrary constants of integration.

To find a particular solution, we look for it in the form $y_{nh}(t)=\alpha\cos(\omega t+\varphi)+\beta\sin(\omega t+\varphi)$. Substituting this into the differential equation, we find two equations
$$ \alpha(1-\omega^2)+2\zeta\omega\beta=0,\qquad -2\zeta\omega\alpha+\beta(1-\omega^2)=1,$$
which determine $\alpha$ and $\beta$:
$$\alpha=-\frac{2\zeta\omega}{(\omega^2-1)^2+4\zeta^2\omega^2},\qquad
\beta=-\frac{\omega^2-1}{(\omega^2-1)^2+4\zeta^2\omega^2}.
$$
Now the general solution is
$$y(t)=y_h(t)+y_{nh}(t)=A\,e^{\lambda_+ t}+B\,e^{\lambda_- t}+\alpha\cos(\omega t+\varphi)+\beta\sin(\omega t+\varphi).$$
Notice that whenever $\zeta>0$, we have $\mathrm{Re}\,\lambda_{\pm}<0$ (it doesn't matter if we have two real roots or they are complex conjugate). Therefore for large $t$ the homogeneous solution, which encodes initial conditions, becomes irrelevant. What remains is harmonic oscillations of frequency $\omega$ and amplitude
$$\mathcal{A}=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}=\left[(\omega^2-1)^2+4\zeta^2\omega^2\right]^{-\frac12}$$
The resonance corresponds to the case when this amplitude is maximal. [For example, if there is no damping ($\zeta=0$) we obtain that $\omega_{res}=1$ as then the amplitude goes to infinity.]  So we have to find the value of $x$ which corresponds to the minimal value of the function
$$ f(x)=(x-1)^2+4\zeta^2x.$$
This gives $x_{min}=1-2\zeta^2\Rightarrow \omega_{res}=\sqrt{1-2\zeta^2}$. [Note, however, that since $x=\omega^2>0$, if $\zeta$ is sufficiently large (strong damping) then the maximal amplitude is achieved as frequency of the external force approaches $0$.]

Comment: Sorry It was not well formulated. It was because I don't understand properly this problem.
I think there is an issue when you calculate the roots, the four is a one.

Comment: @O.L.: You are very welcome!

Comment: Yes @Ambesh $\lambda_{\pm} = \frac{ - b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4 ac}}{2 a}$ $\rightarrow - \frac{2 \zeta}{2} \pm   \frac{ \sqrt{4 (\zeta^2 - 1)}}{2 \cdot 1}$$\rightarrow  -\frac{2 \zeta}{2} \pm \frac{2 \sqrt{\zeta^2  - 1}}{ 2 \cdot 1}$$\rightarrow  -\zeta \pm \sqrt{(\zeta^2 -1})
$

Answer (score 1):

The solution to a damped driven harmonic oscillator is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator#Driven_harmonic_oscillators) under Sinusoidal driving force.  The worst case frequency is $\omega_r=\omega_0\sqrt{1-2\zeta^2}$  To derive that, you assume any initial conditions damp out and look for a steady state solution of the form $y=A\sin (\omega t + \phi + \phi_2)$  Usually the driving force has $\phi=0$ as that doesn't contribute anything to the situation-it just shifts the origin of $t$.  Plug that solution in and you can determine $A$ and $\phi_2$ as a function of $\omega$